# What is this white snake like thing?

Tags: identification, fungus

Is this fungus or what? Appears to be root of something.

Here is the potted plant:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Beaucarnea recurvata, common name Ponytail Palm. Although they will grow happily in the same pot for years, and quite like being a bit rootbound, now that the roots are try to escape looking for more space, its probably time to pot up into something larger, or wider at least. Not much wider, but large enough to accommodate those straying roots,so maybe one size up. Repotting of these is only done when its essential, and it looks as if it is, bit more info on this plant and being rootbound here

http://homeguides.sfgate.com/can-ponytail-palm-become-root-bound-85247.html

Answer (score 3):

It's a root from a pot bound plant.  Fine to leave as is.  Providing a picture of the plant will tell us the species which will help identify if repotting is suggested.

Comment: Added the plant.