# Should I re-pot this Ponytail Palm or wait more?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, palm

This ponytail palm is root-bound for years (3-5 years) and it is still growing. Not sure if this requires re-potting or I should let the plant grow in this same pot?

It's a 12" pot. Never fertilized.Total height of plant is about 3-4'.

[image]
[image]

I asked a question 3 years ago, and I was advised to re-pot this at that time. (yes, it's in the same pot). I couldn't re-pot it for some reason. Now I see that the plant is still growing and don't know if this is the right time to re-pot of not.

https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/27384/14009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's desperate for more root room, even though the topgrowth does not look too bad - repot asap, as previously suggested in the Q & A you link to.

UPDATE: Use a pot one size larger than its current one, although two sizes larger won't do much harm; remove the plant from its current pot and settle into the new pot, filling in with potting soil. As for the potting soil, it needs a fast draining one, such as that you might use for cactus, see here https://www.almanac.com/plant/ponytail-palms. I wouldn't prune the roots myself...

Comment: But what precautions I should take for when re-potting? Since it loves to root-bound, should I pull the plant up and straightawy put it in a bigger pot? or do I need to prune the roots? What soil will be best for this?

Comment: Its related to Agave & Yucca.  It needs well draining soil.  The bulge at the base is the caudex.  This is where it stores water to use during periods of drought.     The larger the pot the larger the plant.